# Blackberry mds connection doesn't work with simulator version 6.0.0

Tags: blackberry

I have a problem with BES connection on top of MDS simulator.
What I'm trying is simple, I want to support all connections types but BIS-B : TCP, WIFI, WAP1/2, BES. I succeeded in implementing TCP, WIFI, WAP1/2, it works with device emulators from 4.5 to 6.0.
For BES, I only get it to work with device emulators versions from 4.5 to 5.0. 
The problem with version 6.0.0 is just that it blocks, I guess the device emulator tries to reach BES service through the MDS simulator but doesn't find it so freezes (call to function HttpConnection.getResponseCode is blocking the app). Nothing appears in the MDS simulator console.

My MDS simulator is 4.1.4.

I tried to browse through the various settings of the phone simulator but didn't find anything relevant. I only saw "bes service : not connected", ok thanks but why?

I also tried to access bes connection through the httpdemo sample provided by RIM, same problem, blocks.

I cannot figure out why it works with previous versions and not latest one. Did I missed something? Is there a special setting for the device emulator or the MDS simulator? Is there something more to add to the url (not only ";deviceside=false") for version 6.0.0 (I browsed the release notes but didn't find anything)?
As Leloo Dallas would say "Please help!"

Hope I'm not wasting your time with a silly question.

Thanks guys (girls?)

Neimad

Comment: Note : I didn't try to reach each time the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

Neimad, the code to use BES/MDS connection should be the same for all OS versions. So if it runs on 4.5/5.0 - then it should also run on OS 6.

Not sure if this is your case - however just have a look to this official RIM info: [BlackBerry MDS Simulator does not launch](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-MDS-Simulator-does-not-launch/ta-p/446126).

Comment: I know that man, that's why I'm so disappointed. Concerning your link, I already know it too, my mds simulator correctly launches and stays open. It gives me bes connection for versions 4.5 to 5.0 but not 6.0, so weird!

Comment: @Neimad: I've just tested Torch 9800 OS 6 simulator + MDS (installed as a part of JDE 6) - works fine. The version of my MDS simulator is probably 4.1.5.26 (at least the following string goes first in the MDS log output: "SCM 4.1.5.26 26 2008/02/06"). Just an idea - could it be you are using MDS from the JDE 4.5 package (so it does not compatible with OS 6 simulators)?